# Dep xxx restored, but was unable to load it with error: Package xxx not found

Tags: git, docker, go, godeps

I have a golang app inside `my-app` (cloned git repo). The folder myapp is on the same place as my Dockerfile. I copy my project in it.
Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.7
RUN go get github.com/tools/godep
ADD priv/.netrc /root/.netrc

WORKDIR /go/src/my-app
ADD ./my-app .

RUN godep restore -v
```

Now the godep restore -v is failing.
A lot of repo's are restored well, some are skipped:

```
godep: Restoring dependency ..
godep: Restoring dependency (if needed): github.com/xxx
godep: Skipping already restored repo
```

It works all fine till the moment it need to restore dependencies which are inside the `my-app` repo?

```
godep: Dep (github.com/otherrepo/random/random) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (github.com/my-name/my-app/subpath)  not found
```

The path exist (on every branch). 
When I `cd` inside my-app I can see the `subpath` folder and I can also visit it on github:

```
https://github.com/my-name/my-repo/tree/branch/subpath
```

What am I missing or what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have setup GOPATH inside Docker container